# REGEX: Find those files that doesn't contain the same link in 2 different html tags

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have more than 1000 html files.  I need to find out with REGEX if one link from `<link tag>` is repeated in another location on the same file.

For example, in the first line there is a `<link tag` with this link `https://mywebsite.com/en/truth.html`.

Down below in an `<img tag` and I have another link `https://mywebsite.com/en/love.html`

```html
<link rel="canonical" href="https://mywebsite.com/en/truth.html" />

text text
    
text

<img src="index_files/flag_lang_de.jpg" width="28" height="19" title="de" alt="de" /></a>&nbsp; <a href="https://mywebsite.com/en/love.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_ru.jpg" width="28" height="19" title="ru" alt="ru" /></a>
```

After using a regex formula, I should find those files that doesn't contain the same link in 2 different html tags. I made a regex, but is not very good.

This can find the first link from the <link tag: `(<link rel="canonical" href="(.*?)" \/>.*?)`
This can find the second link from <img tag: `(alt="de" /></a>&nbsp; <a href=").*?("><img src)`

and I use `?!` to exclude the second link, so the regex is:

FIND: (.matches newline)

`(<link rel="canonical" href="(.*?)" \/>.*?)(?!(alt="de" /></a>&nbsp; <a href=")).*?("><img src)`

But is not working, it finds both link, even if those are the same. I should find the files that doesn't contain the same link up and down.

Comment: sorry, yes, I change. Should be `<link rel="canonical"` instead of meta :)

Comment: Do you consider the two links in your example identical due to them being the same domain, or different due to the html page being different?

Comment: the same domain

Comment: Please edit your post to reflect this. I understood them to be different, since "mywebsite.com/en/truth.html" is not the same string as "mywebsite.com/en/love.html". Also include that you expect the first link to always be in a "<link rel="canonical"" tag and the second to always be in an "<a>" tag and if other information like 'width="28" height="19" title="de" alt="de"' plays any part here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions:

FIND: `(?s)<link\h+rel="canonical"\h*\Khref="([^"]+)"((?!<link).)+?<a href="(?!\1).+?"`

or

FIND:  `(?s)^<link rel.+?https://([^"]+).+?https://(*SKIP)(?!\1)`

or (.matches newline)

FIND: `<link rel="canonical"[^>]*"(https[^"]+)"[^>]*>.*?(\1)`

Thanks to those who people find this answers [HERE](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/21084/regex-find-those-files-that-doesn-t-contain-the-same-link-in-2-different-html-tags)

Comment: Please give an explanation to the solution here in this Answer, not just in a link.

Comment: morning, @Scratte. You get  the explication if you access the link. Cannot copy/paste all the explication, only the solution. This is why I left the link of the other post.

Comment: I understand that you cannot copy'n'paste it all. But this is basically a code-only Answer. Users have to work out for themselves why those expressions work. That is not considered a good Answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty crude, but based on your example above it should be sufficient:

- [`<meta[^>]*"(http[^"]+)"[^>]*>.*?(\1)`](https://regex101.com/r/oRAGH9/3)

[image]

A few things on this:

- I am grabbing the `http...` from a `meta` tag, this assumes an absolute url and not `/` for example, also, if there are multiple urls in any `meta` tag you'd want to examine that as well.
- I'm just using a `.*\1` to see if that captured link occurs anywhere else in the text (even outside a tag) -- if you only want it within a tag, perhaps wrap it in the tags you're looking to find it in, for example: `<a href="\1"`.
- Make sure the dot-matches-newline option is set (or use another character class).

Comment: your regex seems to be good. Please change `http` with `https` Here is a print screen 
 https://snipboard.io/JgT7LB.jpg Ok, it finds only that contains the same link. But I need to find those files that doesn't contain the same link.

Comment: buy the way, @david542  I change on my post. Should be <link rel="canonical" instead of meta :)

Comment: @HellenaCrainicu So what you do is that all the ones that this regex doesn't match, are the ones you're looking for.

Comment: @Scratte yes. But remember the both tags, because those links may be present more then twice in the same file. So, I consider only the first and the last instances of those links

Comment: @HellenaCrainicu sure let me re-read and I'll post an update later. What if you just changed `meta` to `link`, does that work?

Comment: @HellenaCrainicu You did not mention that they may be more than two identical links in the files. Only that "doesn't contain the same link in 2 different html tags". Though one could argue that this Answer doesn't account for this. What if the links are in the "<link" and then two different <a> tags? How does it change that it's there at least twice? Does anything change if the second link is in a different tag than an <a> tag? I think you need to be very clear on what you need in your Question itself.

Comment: those links may occur several times. but I have only one line with `<link rel="canonical" href="https://mywebsite.com/en/truth.html" />` and one single line with 
`<img src="index_files/flag_lang_de.jpg" width="28" height="19" title="de" alt="de" /></a>&nbsp; <a href="https://mywebsite.com/en/love.html"><img src="index_files/flag_lang_ru.jpg" width="28" height="19" title="ru" alt="ru" /></a>`

Answer (score 0):

**FIND:**

```
(?s)<link\s+rel="canonical"\s+href="([^"]+)"(?:(?!<link).)*?<a\s+href="(?!\1).+?"
```

**OR**

```
(?s)<link\s+rel="canonical"\s+href="([^"]+)"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<a\s+href="(?!\1).+?"
```